# Trouble Installing Ardupilot (14.04)

Tags: software-installation, arduino

I am trying to install this .deb package:
http://ardupilot.com/downloads/?did=112

When I try to install it from the Software Center, I get this error:

```
Cannot install 'libqt5gui5:i386'
```

It also mentions trying to use `sudo dpkg-i`.

Here is what I have tried:

1. I followed [this (which I thought was an install)](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/building-the-code-onlinux/) from the terminal

   Result: It seemed to complete ok, but when I search for `ardupilot` nothing with a GUI comes up, but there is no `ardupilot` program directory in my home folder.
2. I have tried `sudo dpkg-i apm_planner2_latest_ubuntu_trusty.deb`

   Result: First: I tried typing as is above from my root directory, but it seems to want to be in the correct folder. It is located in my downloads folder. I seem to have trouble pointing the `dpkg-i` to the correct directory. I have typed `cd ~/downloads` and it says it does not exist in `/home/<user name>/downloads`. I would have expected it to go to `/home/downloads`.
3. I also tried another package installer "Synaptic", but it would not install .deb packages.
4. I have also tried to run repairs on packages using some terminal commands (I forgot what they were). They seemed to run successful, but the package still wont install.

Basically I am to the point where I have tried everything I can think of to get this to install, but its not working. Please help!

Comment: It's `Downloads` with a capital `D`. Try :`sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/apm_planner2_latest_ubuntu_trusty.deb`. Also, there's a space between `dpkg` and `-i`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to download and install the [i386 version](http://ardupilot.com/downloads/?did=112) when you are running [64 bit ubuntu](http://ardupilot.com/downloads/?did=111).

To correct this, run the following commands.

First, purge any existing version and then install gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get purge apmplanner2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Next, download the correct version:

```
wget http://ardupilot.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=111
mv 'download.php?id=111' apm_planner2_latest_ubuntu_trusty64.deb
```

Now, install the correct version using gdebi:

```
sudo gdebi apm_planner2_latest_ubuntu_trusty64.deb
```

Also, the application is named `apmplanner2` which is why you probably couldn't find it.

Comment: Not that gdebi is needed any longer. Just `xdg-open apm_planner2_latest_ubuntu_trusty64.deb` and let the Software Center handle it.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I'll give it a try in the future. The software center has always been so slow that I haven't used it in a while.

Comment: Thank you! I feel dumb for trying to install the i386 version, but that was the issue.

Comment: @user484313 Awesome, don't forget to click the icon to the left to accept this as the solution if this solved your problem, thanks!